# MPEG 4 Audio Support Not Working in Rhythmbox 3.4.4 (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Tags: rhythmbox, aac, m4a

In Rhythmbox 3.4.4 - which is included with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ("Focal Fossa") - there is the option to "rip" music in MPEG-4 Audio (".m4a") format... Underneath said option, there is a big ol' button that says:

*Install additional software required to use this format*

But clicking this button doesn't do anything, at all.

I *did* choose to install Ubuntu Restricted Extras when I did my "clean" install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ("Focal Fossa"), but just in case something went wrong, I re-installed it via Terminal.

Someone also suggested that I check that gstreamer1.0-libav and libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 are installed - they both were.

After checking that the above were installed, I restarted my computer and removed / re-installed Rhythmbox - No change (i.e. Rhythmbox *still* has the same message under MPEG-4 Audio).

This issue affects both my laptop and my tablet.

Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which *specific* package was missing, but this fixed it...

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
```

Obviously do this with Rhythmbox and any other media players you have installed *closed*... Once the installation is complete, you can open them again and the issue *should* be fixed.

Comment: As mentioned in another answer, `gstreamer1.0-libav` was all I needed to be able to play ACC/m4a files.  Good answer structure here, though.

Answer (score 6):

Combining Gregory Opera's answer and info from the answer over [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/884972), this got me working

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav
```

Answer (score 0):

worked my way through Gregory's list, skipped ugly and the first one that wasn't already installed was gstreamer1.0-qt5.
Install gstreamer1.0-qt5 and restart Rhythmbox was successful in playing the m4a file

Comment: FYI, I was having issues "ripping" music in MPEG-4 Audio (".m4a"), not playing it... I was already able to play them without issue.